# Using Hyperion with Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, memory, hyperspectral-sensor, hyperion

I am trying to use Hyperion Data for my project, unfortunately even loading the Image Collection of Hyperion exceeds my maximum 2.5 GB Data Storage.
Hyperion has a revisitrate of 200 Days, so a one Year Daterange should be sufficient to yield only one picture.
I think there is something wrong with my `.filterBounds`
is there some kind of way to prefilter the Collection more precisely?

[Link to GEE script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4dbe5f5fdc52791b57099aa54cb2da09)

Answer (score 1):

Your filtered collection is named 'S2', but you erroneously call the unfiltered 'HyperionCol' using your print statement, which consists of 82152 elements (too much to display).

Unfortunately, no images match with your area of interest and daterange. You can check that using ImageCollection.size().

```js
var S2 = HyperionCol
// Filter collection by time 
.filterDate('2017-01-01','2017-01-31')
// Filter by the region of interest
.filterBounds(geometry);

print(HyperionCol.size(),'Size non filtered HyperionCol'); // size is larger than 5000 elements
print(S2,'Filtered HyperionCol'); // no images are in your date range and area of interest
```